# Div positioning with child element

Tags: css

I have two stacked divs contains child elements and what i want is if I set visibility to hidden to the first div it should disppear and second div under the first one should take the place of first div by maintaining the position of child elements inside the second div.

here is the code.

```
<div id="wrapper">  
     <div id="first" style="top:10px; width:400px; border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">   
        A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog..................
</div>

<div id="second" style="top:100px;width:400px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;">
     <div id="child1" style="margin-left:250px">
            21st, October 2011
     </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:400px;">  
     <div id="first" style="display:none;top:10px; border-style:solid;border-width:1px;">   
        A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog..................
    </div>
     <div id="second" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px;">
         <div id="child1" style="margin-left:250px">
                    21st, October 2011
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

putting the `wrapper` around both objects, then the second `div` will jump up to the first `div`'s position if the first `div` is hidden.

Comment: thank you issac and Kyle..wish i cud've selected both the answers :)

Comment: Cool. Hey, forget the `top` value, use `margin-top` if you want a space there. You've no need to mess with absolute positioning in a case as simple as this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `visibility: hidden;` will only hide the element, it will still reserve space for it in the document flow.

What you want is `display: none;` which will remove the element entirely.

[Example coded here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/dxmsg/). (click the `#second` div to activate.

Comment: gotcha but my main problem is that if i define first div top position I want second one to appear under the first one without mentioning the top and when i set display none to first the second one take the exact position of first one including child elements of second. Can you give me in code so i can check in fiddler.